# RHEL7: How to solve “ import read failed(2)”?

Tags: linux, docker, centos, rhel, docker-registry

I am trying to add Docker’s public key for CS packages using the following command( which is taken from the link https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/install/install-csengine/):

```
sudo rpm --import "https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e"
```

However, I am getting the following error on running the above command:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sks-keyservers.net; Name or service not known
error: https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e: import read failed(2).
```

Is it a firewall issue??

Please let me know if I need to add a host entry in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: It's possible that there's a temporary interruption of that server (it's been down a few times recently) Can you open that url in your browser? https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e

Comment: `Name or service not known` is a DNS failure. Can you resolve that domain name from that machine because it looks like you can't.

Comment: I am able to open the url in the browser  https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e

Comment: If you can download the key with a browser, then `rpmkeys --import key.asc` should work.

Comment: In my case, after install cURL `zypper install -y curl` solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by your firewall, enable / disable it and try again

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

or

```
systemctl enable firewalld
systemctl start firewalld
```